# How do I make users jump to a specific link in a events webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I used an event webpart in the page and add some events. Is there a way for the user to jump to a specific link instead of the detailed page of the event when the user clicks on the event in the widget?

Comment: At first glance I suggest using Quick Links with a custom link added as a `href`.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after my testing the results are that you **at least have to** click on the specific event to show links in *description* or directly in the *link* section:

[image: Img 1]

**Alternative solution**

If you want just to inform your colleagues about some workshop, you can use `News` webpart. There is no such thing as an *Add to calendar* dialog.

Comment: Or can I prevent users from using "add to my calendar"？

Comment: You can achieve it by changing the permissions on the webpart to use a Visitor's group (`read-only`). By default it only has View permissions. But I did not try that.